# flutter dio exception:Content size exceeds specified contentLength

Tags: flutter, dio

Today I was handling the problem, I used dio to upload the file, this is the code:

```
 ///upload the file 
  static Future upFile(String path, UptokenEntity value) async {
    FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
      "key": value.key,
      "filename": value.filename,
      "token": value.token,
      "file": await MultipartFile.fromFile("$path", filename: value.filename),
    });
    var response;
    response = await uphttp.post("", data: formData);

    /*var t=await formData;
    bool testFlag=false;
    if(formData.length==t.length){
      testFlag=true;


    }
    print("上传测试的值为:$testFlag");*/
    return response.data;
  }
```

I met the exception of `Content size exceeds specified contentLength`.
Here is the picture I debug:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBUkN.png)

Comment: The downgrade to dio 2.1.3 resolved my problem

Comment: But the project needs dio  3.0 upper

Answer (score 0):

Add `Content-Length` in your request

```
response = await uphttp.post("", data: formData, options:Options(
 headers: {
      'Content-Length': file.lengthSync().toString() //=> Your file length,
    }
);
```